# Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP 500 error when Upload file to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I want to upload photos to ASP.NET Web API but return error from some photos uploading. I successfully upload to file size 17002 and smaller but I don't upload file size 17345 and bigger. Note: EnableCors on Web API and maxRequestLength="307200" and maxAllowedContentLength="314572800" all of OK. Error (For example when I tried to upload to a photo file size 17345):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:42658/api/MyApi/UploadFile. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I'm using IIS7. Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

i have a same problem, and i found that have a two tags `<httpRuntime>` like:

```
`<httpRuntime  maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>`
```

And the problem was solved that I united them into one like this:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I had the same issue and somehow failed to realize this same (obvious) mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try like below ?

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
      </requestFiltering>
   </security>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, I did try and I tried again after your answer but doesn't work.